# How do I bind the "this" in a function body in IE-8 Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm doing some cross browser testing.  [Initially, I was using the bind() keyword in ECMAScript 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180941/problems-with-adding-an-event-on-a-google-maps-v3-in-ie8-using-bindthis). It's not available in IE8.  As a work-around, I am using some code from Yehuda Katz.  His site suggests using a utility function in lieu of bind() when bind doesn't exist -- It doesn't exist in IE 8.

http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

```
   var bind = function (func, thisValue) {
           return function () {
                   return func.apply(thisValue, arguments);
           }
   }
```

In trying to use it, I'm getting an exception where it says "func.apply".  I'm not passing in a function, I'm passing in an object, so apply() isn't there.  Fine.  But now I'm stuck again and back to square 1.  How do I bind the "this" variable to a function body?

Summary: How do I bind the "this" variable to a function body?

```
<snip>

    MyView.prototype.OnSlider_Change = function (event, ui) {
           this.viewModel.setVariableX(ui.value * 100.0);
    }

<snip>

    $("#Slider").slider({
                   slide: (this.OnSlider_Change).bind(this),
                   change: (this.OnSlider_Change).bind(this)
           });
```

has become

```
   $("#Slider").slider({
           slide: bind(this, this.OnSlider_Change),
           change: bind(this, this.OnSlider_Change)
   });
```

Comment: Yehuda Katz is not JavaScript inventor ;) He's cool guy who knows JavaScript very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just got the argument order wrong for that shim:

```
       slide: bind(this.OnSlider_Change, this),
       change: bind(this.OnSlider_Change, this)
```

Answer (score 6):

With jquery you can use the [proxy method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that implements what your bind method is doing.

```
$("#Slider").slider({
    slide: $.proxy(this.OnSlider_Change, this),
    change: $.proxy(this.OnSlider_Change, this)
});
```